# Error installing makedepend on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, homebrew

When I run `brew install -v makedepend` I get the following error:

> checking whether the C compiler works... no
>
> configure: error: in `/private/tmp/makedepend--xproto-20160925-38800-1pl7ltd/xproto-7.0.28':
>
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to XCode 8 to fix the issue